custom auth filter in spring-boot 3.3.2 always redirecting to "/" after auth
I am trying to create a custom authentication process that will authenticate a user based on information found in the request and create a session for them so that subsequent requests won't require that same data in the request.  For simplicity, my sample auth filter below tries to do so by simply looking for a 'name' GET query param, accepting any name.  After a successful auth, however, the DefaultRedirectStrategy kicks in and redirects the user to '/', where no valid session seems to be recognized and the request subsequently fails the custom auth filter as no 'name' param is found.
I am using spring-boot-starter-parent 3.3.2
auth filter
@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  private static final AntPathRequestMatcher DEFAULT_ANT_PATH_REQUEST_MATCHER = new AntPathRequestMatcher("**","GET");

  public CustomAuthFilter( AuthenticationManager authenticationManager ) {
    super(DEFAULT_ANT_PATH_REQUEST_MATCHER, authenticationManager);
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

    log.debug( "attempting authentication ..." );
    String name = request.getParameter( "name" );

    if ( name == null ) {
      throw new BadCredentialsException("No name provided");
    }

    SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER1");
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(authority);
    CustomAuthToken customAuthToken = new CustomAuthToken( name, grantedAuthorities );

    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate( customAuthToken );
  }

}

auth provider
@Slf4j
@Component
public class CustomAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    CustomAuthToken customAuthToken = (CustomAuthToken) authentication;
    if ( customAuthToken == null || customAuthToken.getPrincipal() == null ) {
      log.warn( "problem with authentication" );
      throw new BadCredentialsException("No name provided");
    }
    log.debug( "setting setAuthenticated to true" );
    customAuthToken.setAuthenticated( true );
    return customAuthToken;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals( CustomAuthToken.class );
  }
}

auth success hangler
@Slf4j
@Component
public class CustomAuthSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

  @Autowired
  HttpSession session;

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if ( authentication instanceof CustomAuthToken ) {
      log.debug( "setting attribute in session" );
      CustomAuthToken customAuthToken = (CustomAuthToken) authentication;
      session.setAttribute( "name", customAuthToken.getPrincipal() );
    } else {
      log.debug( "not an instance of CustomAuthToken" );
    }
    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
  }

}

auth token
public class CustomAuthToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

  private String name;

  public CustomAuthToken(String name, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    super(authorities);
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getCredentials() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getPrincipal() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

controller
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class AppController {

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String indexPage() {
    log.debug( "show index.html" );
    return "index.html";
  }

  @GetMapping("/page2")
  public String pagee2() {
    log.debug( "show page2" );
    return "page2.html";
  }

}

security config
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Autowired
  CustomAuthProvider customAuthProvider;

  @Autowired
  CustomAuthSuccessHandler customAuthSuccessHandler;

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
    return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
    return new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
            new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
            new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
    );
  }


  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                          SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository,
                                          AuthenticationManager authManager) throws Exception {

    CustomAuthFilter customAuthFilter = new CustomAuthFilter(authManager);
    customAuthFilter.setSecurityContextRepository( securityContextRepository );
    customAuthFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(customAuthSuccessHandler);

    return http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .addFilterAt(customAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement( session -> {
              session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
            })
            .authorizeHttpRequests( request -> {
              request.anyRequest().authenticated();
            })
            .authenticationManager( authManager )
            .build();

  }

}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Main Page</h1>
Go to <a href="/page2">Page 2</a>
<br/>
<p th:text="${'Hello ' + #ctx.session.name}" />
<p>Here's a picture of a squirrel:</p>
<img src="/images/squirrel.png" />
</body>
</html>

page2.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Page 2</h1>
<h3 th:text="${#ctx.session.name + ', you're still here?'}" />
</body>
</html>

output
2024-08-03T08:10:35.196-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] org.example.AuthFilterApplication        : Starting AuthFilterApplication using Java 17.0.12 with PID 54305 (/home/user/github/spring-auth-filter/target/classes started by user in /home/user/github/spring-auth-filter)
2024-08-03T08:10:35.218-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] org.example.AuthFilterApplication        : Running with Spring Boot v3.3.2, Spring v6.1.11
2024-08-03T08:10:35.226-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] org.example.AuthFilterApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-08-03T08:10:35.438-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2024-08-03T08:10:35.439-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2024-08-03T08:10:38.904-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-08-03T08:10:38.932-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-08-03T08:10:38.932-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.26]
2024-08-03T08:10:39.026-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-08-03T08:10:39.034-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3586 ms
2024-08-03T08:10:39.475-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] eAuthenticationProviderManagerConfigurer : Global AuthenticationManager configured with AuthenticationProvider bean with name customAuthProvider
2024-08-03T08:10:39.617-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2024-08-03T08:10:39.732-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 4 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2024-08-03T08:10:39.881-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2024-08-03T08:10:39.941-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with filters: DisableEncodeUrlFilter, WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter, SecurityContextHolderFilter, HeaderWriterFilter, CorsFilter, LogoutFilter, CustomAuthFilter, RequestCacheAwareFilter, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter, SessionManagementFilter, ExceptionTranslationFilter, AuthorizationFilter
2024-08-03T08:10:39.951-04:00  WARN 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.a.web.builders.WebSecurity       : 

********************************************************************
**********        Security debugging is enabled.       *************
**********    This may include sensitive information.  *************
**********      Do not use in a production system!     *************
********************************************************************


2024-08-03T08:10:40.073-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2024-08-03T08:10:40.147-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2024-08-03T08:10:40.315-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2024-08-03T08:10:40.395-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-08-03T08:10:40.415-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [  restartedMain] org.example.AuthFilterApplication        : Started AuthFilterApplication in 6.53 seconds (process running for 8.201)
2024-08-03T08:10:58.672-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-08-03T08:10:58.672-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-08-03T08:10:58.672-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2024-08-03T08:10:58.672-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2024-08-03T08:10:58.672-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2024-08-03T08:10:58.673-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@1945f89
2024-08-03T08:10:58.673-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@63d462c8
2024-08-03T08:10:58.674-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='true': request parameters and headers will be shown which may lead to unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2024-08-03T08:10:58.674-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2024-08-03T08:10:58.770-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/?name=Steve':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1de4f799

servletPath:/
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="127", "Not)A;Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-user: ?1
sec-fetch-dest: document
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie: JSESSIONID=BAC60C189F35103AC56E7AA48EE5F1A9


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
  CustomAuthFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


************************************************************


2024-08-03T08:10:58.781-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /?name=Steve
2024-08-03T08:10:58.791-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.e.config.security.CustomAuthFilter     : attempting authentication ...
2024-08-03T08:10:58.793-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.e.config.security.CustomAuthProvider   : setting setAuthenticated to true
2024-08-03T08:10:58.799-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=CustomAuthToken [Principal=Steve, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER1]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@782882f6]
2024-08-03T08:10:58.800-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.e.config.security.CustomAuthFilter     : Set SecurityContextHolder to CustomAuthToken [Principal=Steve, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER1]]
2024-08-03T08:10:58.800-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.e.c.security.CustomAuthSuccessHandler  : setting attribute in session
2024-08-03T08:10:58.801-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to /
2024-08-03T08:10:58.812-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-2] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@48cfe1ff

servletPath:/
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-user: ?1
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="127", "Not)A;Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie: JSESSIONID=BAC60C189F35103AC56E7AA48EE5F1A9


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
  CustomAuthFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


************************************************************


2024-08-03T08:10:58.813-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /
2024-08-03T08:10:58.813-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.e.config.security.CustomAuthFilter     : attempting authentication ...
2024-08-03T08:10:58.813-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-2] .a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler : Sending 401 Unauthorized error
2024-08-03T08:10:58.857-04:00  INFO 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-2] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/error':

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@6604ba42

servletPath:/error
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-user: ?1
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="127", "Not)A;Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie: JSESSIONID=BAC60C189F35103AC56E7AA48EE5F1A9


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
  CustomAuthFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


************************************************************


2024-08-03T08:10:58.858-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2024-08-03T08:10:58.859-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.e.config.security.CustomAuthFilter     : attempting authentication ...
2024-08-03T08:10:58.859-04:00 DEBUG 54305 --- [Auth Filter Test] [nio-8080-exec-2] .a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler : Sending 401 Unauthorized error

Anyone wanting to give this a try locally can just:
$ git clone https://github.com/smaring/spring-auth-filter.git
$ cd spring-auth-filter
$ mvn spring-boot:run

and then drop a URL in a browser with a name param ala
http://localhost:8080?name=Bob

EDIT:
I've noted that if I request http://localhost:8080/page2?name=Bob when the success handler kicks in ...
the request contains
requestDispatcherPath="/page2"

and an attribute in the request is
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.CachedResult -> {HandlerMappingIntrospector$CachedResult@8157} "CachedResult for REQUEST dispatch to '/page2'"

but the success handler itself has
targetUrlParameter = null
defaultTargetUrl = "/"
alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl = false
useReferer = false
redirectStrategy = (DefaultRedirectStrategy@6561)

What is it about a SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler that is actually saved and used?

This is without running your code but it looks like the session after login is created by HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository which means it is stored in the HttpSession, while your filter checks for HttpParams. But this is a just a random guess after reading your logs.

Since you specified new AntPathRequestMatcher("**","GET"):
@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  private static final AntPathRequestMatcher DEFAULT_ANT_PATH_REQUEST_MATCHER = new AntPathRequestMatcher("**","GET");
....

Your filter will work every time, even after authentication, so you will need to replace it with new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login","GET"), for example, or something better

Thanks for the reply.  I was just reading the final comments at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78759393/what-is-the-default-spring-security-behavior-for-requests  and this perked an eyebrow for me.  Then I noticed your comment.  I will play with that and report back the results.

I ended up following a pre authentication model based on https://bwgjoseph.com/spring-security-custom-pre-authentication-flow that ended up doing what I want.

Here is my working example if anyone is interested https://github.com/smaring/spring-pre-auth-filter
